# Integration of finite, real integrand gives imaginary error function, causes problems

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, complex

So far, I have found two questions on Stackexchange with a similar problem, the most recent is [(111297)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111297/strange-behaviour-of-integrals-with-cos-sin-and-exp).  However, the question is over a year old, and reported as a bug.  Nonetheless, the most recent version of *Mathematica* 11.1.1.0 still gives these sorts of results.

My problem is the integral

```
Integrate[Cos[x*Pi*j]*E^(-1 + x)^2, {x, x0, x1}]
```

The domain is always between 0 and 1, though I need some variation for later in the code.  This integrand could not be better behaved.  I can put all sorts of conditions without success:  limits are real, between 0 and 1, upper limit is larger than the lower limit, the $j$ is integer and positive, etc.

No matter what, the answer involves four imaginary error functions.  When I use them, I sometimes get tiny imaginary bits, probably from numerical error.  Nonetheless, it causes problems later in the code.

Since this problem has been around for a long time, according to the previous questions, does that mean that it will never get fixed?  I know that the answer might be technically correct, and that there might be workarounds, but that doesn't mean it isn't a bug.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the integral can be represented using only real numbers / functions? Also, would it be viable to pass the numerical results through `Chop` when you need them later in the code?

Comment: On the other side of the ledger, the fact that the result is in some way not liked does not mean it is a bug (and it isn't).

Comment: As already noted, it is sometimes unavoidable that complex numbers are needed to represent real-valued functions. Just use `Re[]` at the end if you're sure the result ought to be real-valued anyway.

Answer (score 2):

We can justify the use of `Re` by showing that expression returned by Mathematica is real.  First we evaluate the integral, using $k$ as our positive integer parameter:

```
Integrate[Cos[x*π*k]*Exp[(-1 + x)^2], {x, x0, x1}]
```

which gives something like
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}4 e^{\frac{\pi k}4 (\pi  k-4 i)} \left(e^{2 i \pi  k}
   \left(\text{erfi}\left(-\frac{i \pi k}{2}-\rm{x0}+1\right)-\operatorname{erfi}\left(-\frac{i \pi k}{2} -
 \rm{x1}+1\right)\right)+\\\operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac{i \pi k}{2}-\rm{x0}+1\right)-\operatorname{erfi}\left(\frac{i \pi k}{2}-\rm{x1}+1\right)\right)$$
We note the $e^{2i\pi k}$ is unity, since $k$ is an integer.  The other exponential simplifies to $(-1)^k e^{k^2\pi^2/4}$, which is real.  So, the expression contains 4 terms with `Erfi` each with a real coefficient.  More, it contains 2 pairs of terms with `Erfi[z] + Erfi[z*]`, where `z*` is the complex conjugate of `z`.  We can show that `Erfi[z]=Erf[z*]*` as follows.

We know that `Erfi` is defined in terms of `Erf`, that `Erf` is odd and that `Erf[z*]=Erf[z]*`.  So,

$\operatorname{erfi}(z) = -i \operatorname{Erf}(iz) \hspace{2em}$ by definition of `Erfi`

$\hspace{3em}= i \operatorname{Erf}(-iz) \hspace{2em}$ since `Erf` is odd

$\hspace{3em}= i \operatorname{Erf}(iz^*)^* \hspace{2em}$ since `Erf[z*]=Erf[z]*`

$\hspace{3em}= \left[-i \operatorname{Erf}(iz^*) \right]^* \hspace{2em}$

$\hspace{3em}= \operatorname{erfi}(z^*)^*  \hspace{2em}$ by definition of `Erfi`

Thus, the expression return by Mathematica is a sum of two complex conjugates plus a sum of two other complex conjugates.  Thus Mathematica returns an expression that is provably real *when $k$ is an integer*, and we are justified in using `Re` after evaluating the expression.  Also, since we showed `Erfi[z*]=Erfi[z]*`, we could evaluate the `Erfi` function and use two times real part of that result instead of evaluating `Erfi` twice and adding two values that we know are complex conjugates.  That is, `Re[Erfi[z]+Erfi[z*]]=2*Re[Erfi[z]]`.

Properties of `Erf` are from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Properties)