# Why won't mathematica evaluate the integral I've defined?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I defined

```
Integrate[Exp[p_. Cos[x_] + q_. Sin[x_]]*Sin[a_. Cos[x_] + b_. Sin[x_] - m_. x_],
{x_, 0, 2*Pi}] := Sqrt[-1]*Pi*((b - p)^2 + (a + q)^2)^(-m/2)*(((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) 
+ Sqrt[-1]*(2*(p*q + a*b)))^(m/2)*BesselI[m, Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) -     
Sqrt[-1]*(2 (a*p + b*q))]] - ((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) -
Sqrt[-1]*(2 (p*q + a*b)))^(m/2)*BesselI[m, Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) +       
Sqrt[-1]*(2 (a*p + b*q))]])
```

In accordance with the examples given in the mathematica documentation. However, the integral only evaluates for the exact symbolic values p,q,a,b,m. If I try to evaluate any other form of the integral, e.g.

```
Integrate[Exp[Cos[x]+Sin[x]]*Sin[Sin[x]+Cos[x]-x],{x,0,2*Pi}]
```

Mathematica is unable to evaluate the integral. Why doesn't the integral, the way I've defined it, evaluate for any given values of p,q,a,b,m?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Related: [(6169)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6169), [(19534)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19534)

Comment: BTW, what examples are given in the documentation?  (Where are they?)

Answer (score 7):

One problem is that `Exp[y]` evaluates to `Power[E, y]`, so that the integral does not match the (held) pattern with `Exp`.  Another is that other functions sometimes evaluate to other forms, such as `Sin`:

```
Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x]
(* -Sin[x - Cos[x] - Sin[x]] *)
```

Here is a fix that works on the example. I added a constant factor `c_` to take care of the `-1` factoring out of `Sin[]`, and changed `-m_` to `+m_`, *mutatis mutandis*.  Other examples may simplify in other ways, so some testing may be necessary to cover all possible use-cases.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
 Unprotect[Integrate];
 Integrate[
   c_. Power[E, p_. Cos[x_] + q_. Sin[x_]]*
    Sin[a_. Cos[x_] + b_. Sin[x_] + m_. x_], {x_, 0, 2*Pi}] := 
  c (Sqrt[-1]*
     Pi*((b - p)^2 + (a + q)^2)^(m/2) * 
       (((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) + Sqrt[-1]*(2*(p*q + a*b)))^(-m/2) * 
        BesselI[-m, Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) - Sqrt[-1]*(2 (a*p + b*q))]] - 
      ((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) - Sqrt[-1]*(2 (p*q + a*b)))^(-m/2)*
        BesselI[-m, Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) + Sqrt[-1]*(2 (a*p + b*q))]]));
 Protect[Integrate];
 Integrate[Exp[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]*Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
 ]
(*
 -2 I π (-(1/2) (-1)^(3/4) BesselI[1, 2 (-1)^(1/4)] + 
    1/2 (-1)^(1/4) BesselI[1, 2 (-1)^(3/4)])
*)
```

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/what-does-internalinheritedblock-do) for `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``.

Answer (score 5):

Michael E2 and Bob have solved the integral. Here is an alternative method which might be of interest as well. I have used the similar method already in [How to solve this integration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111284/how-to-solve-this-integration/111292#111292).

We solve the integral transforming it into a complex contour integral which, after a simple binomial expansion, can easily be soved by the Cauchy theorem. The remaining infinte sum can be expressed by a hypergeometric function which reduces to a modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Let

```
f := Exp[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]*Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x]
g := Integrate[f, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

First we shall use the exponential form of the Sin[] outside the Exp[] function in f (in the end we take the imaginary part)

```
Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x] == Im[Exp[I (Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x)]];
ComplexExpand[%]

(* Out[812]= True *)
```

so that the argument of the `Exp[]` function becomes

```
Cos[x] + Sin[x] + I (Cos[x] + Sin[x] - x)
```

which can be written as

```
Exp[I x] + I Exp[-I x] - I x
```

The integral `g` then becomes

```
g := Integrate[Exp[Exp[I x] + I Exp[-I x] - I x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Now with the substitution

```
{z -> Exp[-I x], dz = -I z dx};
```

`g` simplifies to a contour integral around the origin

```
h = I  Integrate[Exp[1/z + I z], {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]

(* Out[814]= Integrate[E^(1/z + I z), {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}] *)
```

As this integral is returned unevaluated we expand the Exp[] function in a power series.

A typical term can in turn be expanded into a binomial sum

```
(1/z + I z)^n == Sum[Binomial[n, k] z^-k (I z)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}] == 
  Sum[Binomial[n, k] z^(n - 2 k) I^(n - k), {k, 0, n}];
```

Now, by the Cauchy theorem, the contour integral of integer powers of `z` is only different from zero for the first negative power. Examples are

```
Table[{m, Integrate[z^m, {z, 1, I, -1, -I, 1}]}, {m, -2, 1}]

(* Out[820]= {{-2, 0}, {-1, 2 I \[Pi]}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}} *)
```

Hence we have the condition

```
Reduce[n - 2 k == -1, Integers ] /. C[1] -> m

(* Out[827]= m \[Element] Integers && k == m && n == -1 + 2 m *)
```

Taking into account the factor `2 \[Pi] I` from the integration and the `1/n!` from the `Exp[]` function we arrive at the sum which is immediatey evaluated by Mathematica:

```
h1 = 2 \[Pi] Sum[
   1/(2 m - 1)! Binomial[2 m - 1, m] I^(m - 1), {m, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[843]= -2 (-1)^(3/4) \[Pi] BesselI[1, 2 (-1)^(1/4)] *)
```

The original integral is the imaginary part of `h1`.

Numerically

```
h1 // N

(* Out[868]= 5.76177 + 3.09803 I *)
```

Another form of h1 is obtained by expressing (-1) in exponential form

```
h1 /. (-1)^c_ -> Exp[I \[Pi] c]

(* Out[865]= -2 E^((3 I \[Pi])/4) \[Pi] BesselI[1, 2 E^((I \[Pi])/4)] *)
```

Which can be simplified to

```
FullSimplify[%]

(* Out[866]= 2 \[Pi] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, I] *)

% // N

(* Out[867]= 5.76177 + 3.09803 I *)
```

Comment: N.B. $I_n(z)$ is a *modified* Bessel function of the first kind; it's $Y_n(z)$ that's a Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: @J.M. corrected, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than define a function, you can define a replacement rule using [Hold](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and [RuleDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)

```
rule = Hold[Integrate[
     Exp[p_. Cos[x_] + q_. Sin[x_]]*
      Sin[a_. Cos[x_] + b_. Sin[x_] - m_. x_], {x_, 0, 2 Pi}]] :>
   I*Pi*((b - p)^2 + (a + q)^2)^(-m/
       2)*(((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) + I*(2*(p*q + a*b)))^(m/2)*
       BesselI[m, 
        Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) - 
          I*(2 (a*p + b*q))]] - ((p^2 - q^2 + a^2 - b^2) - 
          I*(2 (p*q + a*b)))^(m/2)*
       BesselI[m, Sqrt[(p^2 + q^2 - a^2 - b^2) + I*(2 (a*p + b*q))]]);

Hold[Integrate[
    Exp[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]*Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]] /. 
  rule // Simplify

(*  (-(-1)^(1/4))*Pi*
   (BesselI[1, 2*(-1)^(1/4)] + 
      I*BesselI[1, 2*(-1)^(3/4)])  *)
```

With inexact numerical values and using [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to remove the negligible imaginary artifact

```
% // N // Chop

(*  3.09803  *)
```

Verifying with [NIntegrate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

```
NIntegrate[Exp[Cos[x] + Sin[x]]*Sin[Sin[x] + Cos[x] - x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

(*  3.09803  *)
```